# Max in every row and column in bimatrix game

Tags: matrix

[image]

I want to find the maximum value in each column by comparing only the first elements (-8 and 10) and (0 and -1) and maximum value in each row by comparing only the second elements {-8 and -10) and (0 and -1).Apparent (-8,-8) is the cell where are the max in both cases.So i want this result.I do not know how to do it with a matrix of this kind so I split the matrix into two `A={{-8,0},{-10,-1}}and B={{-8,-10},{0,-1}} and I found max`
Relust is {0,-8} {0,-8} but i want to show {-8,-8} and if possible you do not have to separate the matrix like this.

Comment: I find it hard to grasp what you want. Please be more precise. For example: What do you want to find? A _value_ as you said or a _position_?

Comment: Nash equilibria, such as the ones discussed here, are reported according to positions, not payoffs. The correct answer is not {-8,-8} but {1,1}.

Answer (score 2):

```
(* payoff matrix: *)
payoff = {{{-8, -8}, {0, -10}}, {{-10, 0}, {-1, -1}}}
(* player 1 payoffs: *)
p01 = Map[First, payoff, {2}]
(* conditional best moves for player 1: *)
moves01 = Last /@ Ordering /@ Transpose[p01]
(* conditional payoffs for player 1: *)
payoffs01 = Extract[p01, MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, moves01]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved upon the answer by @Alan to show Player 2's responses and the coordinates of the equilibria (joint maxima). For a 2*3 (i,j) matrix,

```
payoff = {{{-8, -8}, {0, -10}}, {{-10, 0}, {-1, -1}}, {{-12, 0}, {1, 1}}};
p01 = Map[First, payoff, {2}];
p02 = Map[First, RotateLeft[payoff, {0, 0, -1}], {2}];
moves01 = Last /@ Ordering /@ Transpose[p01]
moves02 = Last /@ Ordering /@ p02
eq = Flatten /@ Table[If[{moves01[[i]], i} == {j, moves02[[j]]},{moves01[[i]], i}, Nothing], 
{i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

The output is the optimal moves for each player and the position of the equilibria in the matrix.

> {1, 3}
>
> {1, 1, 2}
>
> {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}

**The code does NOT take into account indifference (two equal maximum values in each column). It will report only one.**

The payoffs at equilibria are given by (apologies for elegance)

```
Table[Extract[payoff, eq[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

> {{-8, -8}, {1, 1}}

Comment: When I run this code `Table[Extract[payoff, eq[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]`, it gives me these mistakes `Part::partd: Part specification eq[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>Extract::psl: Position specification eq[[1]] in Extract[{{{-8,-8},{0,-10}},{{-10,0},{-1,-1}},{{-12,0},{1,1}}},eq[[1]]] is not an integer or a list of integers. >>Part::partd: Part specification eq[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>` and I do not know how to fix them. Could this be for my version Wolfram mathematica 8.0?

Comment: add eq= before the line Flatten/@etc.

Comment: I did it but again, such a mistake and no result.

Comment: You are supposed to use both the first and the second block of code I provide, not just the last single line. I just tested it and it works fine.